# Util files within Streamlit application

Tags: streamlit

I am building an app based on the [Streamlit](https://streamlit.io/) frame-work. Within the App, I need to build a logic for connecting to a data base and run the CRUD operation.

I'd like to push the database operations to an external file like `db.py`, import that and then use it within the Streamlit app. Can this be done? If so, what should the folder structure look like and how can I import such a `db.py` components?

I looked at various discussions. They talk about abstracting the `st.` calls but not necessarily on moving the logic to a generic `lib` or `util` file. For example [this discussion](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-project-folder-structure-for-medium-sized-apps/5272) talks about a mechanism to make the UI more maintainable.

Comment: I put my logic code files under modules folder and ui code files under pages. My main streamlit file is on the same level with modules and pages folders. The files under modules serves as utility for each file under pages folder and of the main file. You can import functions, etc. as you normally do in python.